# What is the IP 10.127.127.1 in server 2012

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, wins

I Installed Server 2012 and install `winsserver` when I start it, winsserver know server with `10.127.127.1` Ip Address?
What this ip?
I not set this ip to my computer

my computer ip is 192.168.0.20

please help

[image]

Comment: That should be you.

Isn't that your IP address? Isn't KPSDOMAIN your domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[10.127.127.1](http://who.is/whois-ip/ip-address/10.127.127.1):

```
NetRange:       10.0.0.0 - 10.255.255.255
CIDR:           10.0.0.0/8
NetName:        PRIVATE-ADDRESS-ABLK-RFC1918-IANA-RESERVED
NetHandle:      NET-10-0-0-0-1
Parent:          ()
NetType:        IANA Special Use
OriginAS:       
Organization:   Internet Assigned Numbers Authority (IANA)
RegDate:        
Updated:        2013-08-30
Comment:        These addresses are in use by many millions of independently operated networks, which might be as small as a single computer connected to a home gateway, and are automatically configured in hundreds of millions of devices.  They are only intended for use within a private context  and traffic that needs to cross the Internet will need to use a different, unique address.
Comment:        
Comment:        These addresses can be used by anyone without any need to coordinate with IANA or an Internet registry.  The traffic from these addresses does not come from ICANN or IANA.  We are not the source of activity you may see on logs or in e-mail records.  Please refer to http://www.iana.org/abuse/answers
Comment:        
Comment:        These addresses were assigned by the IETF, the organization that develops Internet protocols, in the Best Current Practice document, RFC 1918 which can be found at:
Comment:        http://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc1918
Ref:            http://whois.arin.net/rest/net/NET-10-0-0-0-1

OrgName:        Internet Assigned Numbers Authority
OrgId:          IANA
Address:        12025 Waterfront Drive
Address:        Suite 300
City:           Los Angeles
StateProv:      CA
PostalCode:     90292
Country:        US
RegDate:        
Updated:        2012-08-31
Ref:            http://whois.arin.net/rest/org/IANA

OrgTechHandle: IANA-IP-ARIN
OrgTechName:   ICANN
OrgTechPhone:  +1-310-301-5820 
OrgTechEmail:  abuse@iana.org
OrgTechRef:    http://whois.arin.net/rest/poc/IANA-IP-ARIN

OrgAbuseHandle: IANA-IP-ARIN
OrgAbuseName:   ICANN
OrgAbusePhone:  +1-310-301-5820 
OrgAbuseEmail:  abuse@iana.org
OrgAbuseRef:    http://whois.arin.net/rest/poc/IANA-IP-ARIN
```